# Swift EXC_Bad_Access on OpenGL call

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I get this error when I compile and run the app a lot. Normally I have to hit stop in Xcode and run it again. Sometimes it appears, other times it doesn't. Really annoying.

Here is my code:

```
func createTextures() {
        let width = 2048;
        let height = 2048;

        texBuffer = GLubyte();

        for (var i = 0; i < foregroundTex.count; i++) {

            if (textures[i + 1] != "null") {
                glGenTextures(1, &foregroundTex[i]);

                glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), foregroundTex[i]);

                glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

                glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR);
                glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR);

                glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLint(0), GLint(GL_RGBA), GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), GLint(0), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &texBuffer);
```

I get **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** on the last OpenGL call `glTexImage2D()`.

I think it's coming from `texBuffer` variable. Perhaps I'm not initializing it properly? I don't know how else to initialize it in Swift to hold the texture buffer.

Comment: Have you tried using just `GL_RGBA` without `GLint()` in `glTexImage2D`?

Answer (score 0):

`texbuffer` needs to hold more than one byte. `malloc` with `width * height * 4`:

```
var texBuffer = malloc(width*height*4)
```